# Improving database query speed with Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Edit - I am using Windows 10

Is there a faster alternative to pd._read_sql_query for a MS SQL database?

I was using pandas to read the data and add some columns and calculations on the data. I have cut out most of the alterations now and I am basically just reading (1-2 million rows per day at a time; my query is to read all of the data from the previous date) the data and saving it to a local database (Postgres).

The server I am connecting to is across the world and I have no privileges at all other than to query for the data. I want the solution to remain in Python if possible. I'd like to speed it up though and remove any overhead. Also, you can see that I am writing a file to disk temporarily and then opening it to COPY FROM STDIN. Is there a way to skip the file creation? It is sometimes over 500mb which seems like a waste.

```
engine = create_engine(engine_name)
query = 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE row_date = %s;'
df = pd.read_sql_query(query.format(table_name), engine, params={query_date})
df.to_csv('../raw/temp_table.csv', index=False)
df= open('../raw/temp_table.csv')
process_file(conn=pg_engine, table_name=table_name, file_object=df)
```

Comment: what is your local OS (where your PostgreSQL is running)?

Comment: Windows 10, sorry. Added that to OP

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

you can also try to unload data using [bcp utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.110).aspx), which might be lot faster compared to `pd.read_sql()`, but you will need a local installation of `Microsoft Command Line Utilities for SQL Server`

After that you can use PostgreSQL's `COPY ... FROM ...`...

**OLD answer:**

you can try to write your DF directly to PostgreSQL (skipping the `df.to_csv(...)` and `df= open('../raw/temp_table.csv')` parts):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(engine_name)
query = 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE row_date = %s;'
df = pd.read_sql_query(query.format(table_name), engine, params={query_date})

pg_engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname')
df.to_sql(table_name, pg_engine, if_exists='append')
```

Just test whether it's faster compared to `COPY FROM STDIN`...

Comment: I used to use to_sql but it was a lot slower actually (even with the time it takes to create a file and read it again). In your code, you are not using df = pd.read_ anywhere. Is it not necessary, or did you just leave that portion  out? I suppose I would need it because I need to specify the date I am querying for.

Comment: @trench, in this case i don't think your can speed it up a lot, because the `COPY ...` PostgreSQL command is specifically designed for loading/unloading data and it's already pretty optimized. You can try to drop indexes on your PostgreSQL table before loading and recreate it after the load is done

Comment: Ah yes, to be clear, I am happy with the COPY FROM speed. It works quite fast. My original query (read_sql_query) with pandas takes forever though and that's what I am hoping to replace. Also, writing the temporary.csv file takes a long time as well. I think it takes around 1500 seconds or so just to query for the data and a decent amount of time to write the 500mb temp file. I will look at your bcp utility suggestion